# Resuming a countdown when poping to root view

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer

I am new to iPhone Development, and am making a countdown project using navigation controller and storyboard. My application has two views. The first view only has one button. When this button is clicked, it goes to the second view. The second view has the  countdown objects. My problem is that when the countdown is running in second view, if I go back to first view and then hit the button to go to the second view, the countdown is no longer running.

Here is the code:

**view1.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "view2.h"

@interface view1: UIViewController

-(IBAction)nextpage:(id)sender;

@end
```

**view1.m**

```
@implementation view1


-(IBAction)nextpage:(id)sender
{
    view2 *next=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondview"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
}

@end
```

**view2.h**

```
@interface view2 : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
    IBOutlet UITextField *field;

    NSTimer *theTimer;
    NSDate *targetDate;
    NSCalendar *cal;
    NSDateComponents *components;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextField *field;
-(IBAction)back_first_view;
@end
```

**view2.m**

```
@implementation view2
@synthesize lbl,field;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    cal = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] retain];
    components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    if (theTimer != nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSString *input = field.text;
    NSArray *timeSplit = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSUInteger hours =  [[timeSplit objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    NSUInteger minutes =  [[timeSplit objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    [dateComponents setHour:hours];
    [dateComponents setMinute:minutes];

    if (!targetDate) {
        targetDate = [[cal dateFromComponents:dateComponents] retain];
    }
    else {
        targetDate = nil;
        targetDate = [[cal dateFromComponents:dateComponents] retain];
    }

    if ([targetDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
        theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [self hideKeyboard];
    }
    else {
        targetDate = nil;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Cannot countdown because time is before now" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}

- (void)tick {
    if ([targetDate timeIntervalSinceNow] <= 0) {
        //Checks if the countdown completed

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Countdown Completed" message:@"YAY! The countdown has complete" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        return;
    }
    components = [cal components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:targetDate options:0];

    NSInteger hours = [components hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
    NSInteger seconds = [components second];

    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Hours\n%i Minutes\n%i Seconds\n", hours, minutes, seconds];
    lbl.text = output;
}

- (void)hideKeyboard {
    if ([field isFirstResponder]) [field resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)back_first_view
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
 @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this method to,

```
- (IBAction)nextpage:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.next animated:YES];
}
```

And add the first line to your viewDidLoad or any such methods,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad]; //Always keep super call as first call in a method
       self.next = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondview"];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And declare next in .h file @interface as,

```
@interface view1 : UIViewController
{

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) view2 *next;
```

Each and and every time when you are going to next page, you were creating a new `view2`, which you need to change.

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply, but when change method and add first line viewdidload , not running application.error undeclared next in nextpage method.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to mention, you need to declare view2 *next in .h file, since you need to use it in multiple methods in class now. Please declare it in .h and file and check it. I will update my answer.

Comment: sorry application not runnig,I guess I can't do it, if you look at project,you'll find https://github.com/fotosit/countdown/downloads web adress, thanks for your helps

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it. I am able to run your app and it looks great after the above change. Check it.

Comment: Hope you understood that, the issue was with view2 getting released. Since I have added it as @property, it is retained unless it goes out of memory.

Comment: well how to solve this problem use appdelegate ? do you know the answer?

Comment: Yes, you need to declare NSTimer *theTimer as Property in appdelegate.h similar to view2 *next in above case. And then always use it as '[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] theTimer]' instead of 'theTimer' in your view2 class. Remember to import AppDelegate.h in your view2. You have to remove NSTimer *theTimer declared in your view2.h file. If you want to set some value as theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimer..], do it as [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setTheTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimer...]];

Comment: thank you so much, i can understood, your answers was very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using a `UINavigationController`, when you navigate back from `View2` to `View1`, the `View2` instance (and the timer running on it) is destroyed.  When you navigate to `View2` a second time, it's a brand-new instance.

For this to behave as you expect, you have to keep the timer alive somehow.  You could modify your app delegate to manage the timer, and have `View2` get its timer info from the delegate (for example).